# Elements are overlapping to an image when I am resizing the browser

Tags: html, css, web

I am developing a simple portfolio website . But when I am resizing by browser elements are overlapping the backgorund image .

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="main-heading">
            <h1>Jegath S</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="desc">
            <p>
               I am a web developer and designer
               from INDIA . I engoy building anything
               using code . Need a website ?
               Leave it to me :)
           </p>
        </div>

        <div class="explore-button">
            <button class="btn"><a href="#works">Explore</a></button>
        </div>

        <div class="social-media">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the css code

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body ,html{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: f6f6f6;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container{
    font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
    background-image: url(../images/bg-img.jpg) ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-position: right;
    position: relative  ;
}

.main-heading{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    top: 180px;
    left: 565px;
    display: inline-block; 
}

.desc{
    width: 304px;
    text-align: justify;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 410px;
    line-height: 35px;
}

.explore-button a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn{
    width: 110px;
    height: 42px;
    background: #9A3FE0;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 570px;
    left: 500px;
}


.social-media .fa{
    font-size: 25px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 45px;

}

.social-media .fa-facebook{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.social-media .fa-envelope{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
}

.social-media .fa-phone{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
}
```

Please give me a solution .

This was the image when browser is in full width

[image: This was the image when browser is in full width]

This was the image when browser is resized

[image: This was the image when browser is resized]

It will be so helpful if anyone can suggest me a solution . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because on your main-heading class you wrote: "left:565px;". The browser did what you told him to and kept the h1 to 565 no matter the size of the device you are using. That goes for the desc class and the explore button too. In order to make it mobile friendly you need to use media-queries. Find more information about them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp). What media queries do is that you can write custom css depending on the device width. So that they are mobile friendly.If you don't wanna bother with media queries you can instead position the h1, the paragraph and the button with right:x px; instead of left:x px;

Comment: Thank you so much . By using "right :x px; " instead of "left" solved my problem...Thankyou so much. I am a newbie.. :-)

Comment: Everybody was stuck at some point or another, glad that i could help

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the image and text to overlap then make 2 div and assign right div the image as background image and on left div give your text. In that case they won't ever overlap.

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="container col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 right">
    Hi this is the text area. Write anything here.
  </div>

  <div class="container col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 left">

  </div>
</div>


    .left {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ff0;
}

.right {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

This is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r7pL5aub/1/